# Why is putchar() printing out the char with the "%" symbol?

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

I have the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    putchar(c);

    return 0;
}
```

and after compiling and running, when I input `k` for example, it prints out `k%`.
Why is it printing out `%`?

Edit: I tested a few things out and realized that it's the shell (I'm using zsh with oh-my-zsh configuration which is pretty awesome) that's doing that in order to get to a new line. I attached putchar('\n') at the end of the `main()` function and it doesn't print that out. Thanks for the helpful comments.

(Please let me know the reasons for the downvotes so I could improve my further questions in the future)

Comment: Are you sure it's not some other program printing the `%`?

Comment: Nitpick: `getchar` returns and `putchar` expects `int` datatype.

Comment: shell prompt ..

Comment: Add `putchar('\n')` at the end of `main` and see what happens.

Comment: Your code is not the reason why % is being shown. It's your ide or something else that is printing %. I have tested your programme in ubuntu terminal. It's showing correct. Tell me where are you running the code?

Comment: Nitpick: `main()` should be `int main (void)`, and you should `return 0;` at the end. Technically, this code is non-standard C, so your code invokes undefined behaviour

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I love how perfectly good code becomes "undefined behaviour" overnight when a new version of the standard gets ratified by ISO. Or does it happen when your national standards body votes to accept it? There must be a period of time when the same code is undefined in the USA but is perfectly good in Brazil then? I'm confused.

Comment: Change your prompt to something recognisable in your login dot file.

Comment: @n.m.: This could could be considered valid C89 code. But since then, C99 and C11 have been published, and they removed the implicit `int` return type from the standard. This code is, and will always be standard for a C89 compiler, its behaviour is undefined if you run it past a C99 (or C11) compliant compiler though. Geography doesn't matter. Given that C89 is still fairly common (default compiler mode of gcc for example is gnu89), many compilers will be happy to churn out a working binary, but you'll hit a snag once you run `gcc -std=c99 code.c -Wall`, because of the UB according to C99

Comment: Once a new C standard is released, it's _"the"_ standard. Same in Brazil, UK, US, or South-Pole. It just doesn't affect you unless you decide to use a different compiler that implemented the latest version of the language. TL;TR: code that was fully standard compliant yesterday, and followed the C89 standard will always be free of undefined behaviour, provided you compile it as C89 code. OP did not specify what standard he's using, but he did say he's new/learning C. I figured he might as well adopt the latest standards from the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things could be causing that `%` sign to appear:

Your program outputs `k` *without* a new line, and your shell prompt just looks like this:

```
%
```

Meaning that you run the program like so:

```
% ./a.out
k //getchar
k% //putchar + exit + shell prompt
```

So in short: the % isn't part of the output.

There is of course the problem with your code triggering UB: the implicit `int` return type is no longer part of the C standard since C99 and up, and your `main` function is not quite right, some standard compliant main functions are:

```
int main(void);
int main (int argc, char **argv);
int main (int argc, char *argv[]);
```

using `()` is not the same thing.

Lastly, you're not returning anything from `main`, which you should do, just add `return 0` at the end.